# Find the limit of the product series ...

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2^n + 1)(2^n+2)\cdots(2^n+n)}{\sqrt 2^{3n}}
$$

I tried using Cesaro-Stolz on it and I still could not get in a human form.

Comment: I formatted your post to comply with our standards for math expressions (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more details on how). Please check to see whether I did it correctly (Iin particular I'm worried I did the exponents wrong; it's impossible to know whether `2^n+k` means $2^n + k$ or $2^{n+k}$).

Comment: @Arthur Oops I overrid your edit, didn't mean to.

Comment: @Don Please do not "overedit" OP's content, especially if he may not understand it. I rollback your version.

Comment: hint $2^n+k>2^n$ seems numerator is way larger than denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{(2^n + 1)(2^n+2)\cdots(2^n+n)}{\sqrt 2^{\ 3n}} 
> \frac{(2^n)(2^n)\cdots(2^n)}{\sqrt 2^{\ n} \times \sqrt2^{\ n} \times \sqrt 2^{\ n}} = \left(\frac{ 2}{\sqrt2}\right)^{3n} \times \left({2^n}\right)^{n-3}
> \sqrt 2^{\ 3n}
$$

for $n > 3$.